# Leaving out "the" in an enumeration where elements are linked

Tags: grammaticality

I'm having a discussion with a colleague on the following sentence:

> The objective is to assess the integrity of the servers and data they contain.

In my opinion, it should either be

> ... of the servers and the data they contain

or

> ... of the servers and their data.

My colleague feels the *the* before *data* can be left out because it's already used in front of *servers*.

Normally, this sounds ok to me. For example:

> I went to the supermarket, library and police station.

I feel the original sentence is wrong because of the fact that *data* is related to *server* because it makes a reference to it (*they*).

Comment: So, you went to a combination supermarket-library-police station? This isn't a grammar question, but a semantics question.

Comment: It's hard to separate grammar and semantics in a question like this (+1).  @Dauntless, I think your two alternatives make the meaning clearer - they both read right to me.

Comment: To me, the clunkiness stems from a bit of an agreement issue as to whether there is one objective or two. If you want to stick with the idea of one objective, you may want to collect the two items in the predicate more closely. I like the dependency idea (and (of?) their data), but you can also use words like *along with*, or *together with* to help